# Show a service's status to the user

Tags: client-server, docker, monitoring, kubernetes

Some design thoughts on an application that is mostly event driven using kubernetes and docker.

The application is a web based application, a single page one. It shows updates from the back-end such as showing current stock of an item in the inventory. It is pretty real-time, in the sense if an item was sold, it stock gets refreshed in the UI dynamically.
Given this, if the back-end service is not available to send an update to the user-interface, a message has to be shown in the user interface indicating that the updates are currently unavailable.

To address this, **current thoughts are like this** :
Implement a lightweight container in the same pod (like a side car). This container will check the availability of the service periodically by checking a URL(of the service container). It sends an event when available(a-la- heartbeat) If the service is 'down' it sends a "DOWN" that will be streamed to the client side. The client will render message using this - and starts to watch for an "UP" event to remove the message.

This approach can be implemented for each of such back-end service, but will have very similar implementations across the board that violates DRY and causes other corner cases.

Is there a standard pattern for this situation ? I was thinking of leveraging a monitoring solution like "Prometheus" and use a web hook to send the event for "UP" and "DOWN", but still there is some clutter on the client side.

Any other ideas for this ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you are working with a microservices architecture, each service should assume that any other service it communicates with may be down in any given moment. Therefore, the frontend should be able to handle communication problems, like when a REST endpoint is not available, or a pipe is broken. If a frontend instance can not reach any backend, it could update the UI and simply retry. A side-car is not required for this. *You can keep your code DRY by wrapping your calls in a function that would handle failures*. When using a stateful connection like a socket, there should be event handlers for broken connections.

The tricky part is, when given service has multiple instances (which is a necessity if high availability is a concern). In that case, you would need to check the status of each pod and only connect to those which are currently UP.
Using [kubernetes liveliness/readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) is the way to do this. In short, kubernetes will probe the URL and decide whether the service is healthy (2xx response code) or not. Unhealthy pods will not get any requests, and will be restarted if they do not recover in the given time. Frontend would then just check if there is a reachable backend at any given time.

Comment: Thanks for the insight - i have a socket based implementation, which has a bunch of data flowing (application data and envents) to the client side. So in your view, a filter at the client side to handle absence of a "heartbeat" would be required. This will make it a very complex implementation if I need to keep an eye on more than a few services -- any thoughts?

Comment: You could add a health endpoint (REST) on the server side, which also serves as the kubernetes health endpoint, and run an async timer thread that checks the status regularly. That way it would be separated from your main logic, and you could probably reuse the code for other components.

Comment: OK so ultimately, these type of scenarios require a heart beat originating from the server side - and on the client, a handler that can be configured to listen for various "types" of heartbeats and take action on absence of a missed heartbeat (configurable number)